# Dynamic Row Addition in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

This is my domain class

```
class Pen implements Serializable {
    Long id
    String symbol
    String companyName
}
```

This is my form

```
@Validateable
class PenForm {
    List<Pen> pens = [].withLazyDefault {new Pen()}
}
```

This is my controller

```
class PenController {

    def save = { PenForm form ->
        def retList = []

        retList = penService.savePens(form) //saves pen object
        render(view:"index", model:["command":retList])
    }

    def addMoreRows() {
        println params
        render(template: "pen", model: ['pen':new Pen() ,'i':7]) //this will return newly generated row index
    }
}
```

I call controller for save and for adding dynamic row to the current list of **Pen**.

This is my index.gsp

```
<g:form>
    <div >
        <table id="penTable" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Ticker Symbol</th>
                <th>Company Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <g:each in="${command}" var="pen" status="i">
                    <g:render template="pen" model="['pen': pen, 'i':i]"/> //the template "pen" just renders the rows using the model provided
                </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <g:actionSubmit value="save"/>
</g:form>
```

I am using this script to dynamically add the rows

```
$("#addRowsLink").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = '${g.createLink(controller: 'pen', action: 'addMoreRows')}';
   $.get(url, function(html) {
       $("#penTable>tbody").append(html);
   });
});
```

This is my _pen.gsp

```
<tr>
<g:hiddenField name="pens[$i].id" value="${pen?.id}"/>
<td><g:textField name="pens[$i].tickerSymbol" value="${pen?.tickerSymbol}"/></td>
<td><g:textField name="pens[$i].companyName" value="${pen?.companyName}"/></td>
</tr>
```

I am quite new to Grails. Here, I am able to bind the current domain to the form and I am able to update the current values. But when I add rows dynamically, the form object always show the new entry as null.
Is there any way to add rows dynamically?

**EDIT** I am ok with changing the form approach to something else. Is this any way I can fetch the collection of objects() of same domain class from view.

Comment: In `addMoreRows` the `i` passed to the template is always **7**, is it right? Also can you please post the contents of `pen` template

Comment: One more thing, take a look here http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/10/groovy-goodness-create-list-with.html. It seems `withLazyDefault` fills the gaps with `null`. You might want to use `withEagerDefault` instead.

Comment: @AshrafPurno The value 7 is just for testing. I thought of an approach of fetching existing number of rows in addMoreRows() action and return the next index. I have updated the code and included the _pen.gsp.